# Postgresql and OSX

Tags: sql, database, xcode, macos, postgresql

I have a project that's in the design phase and looking at my options have decided on using Postgresql for the application backend because of licensing and features. I have searched around but I am unable to find any solid information on using Postgresql in Xcode or even with OSX applications. Could someone point me in the right direction any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Java + PgJDBC; C with `libpq`; C with `libpq` and `libpqtypes`; C with `unixODBC` via `psqlODBC` and its use of `libpq`; Ruby and the `Pg` gem; Python and `psycopg2`; you've got lots of options.

Answer (score 3):

You have not given quite a lot of context.

On the application side there are quite a few pieces of software running under OS X that interface with PostgreSQL, for example the standard GUI pgAdmin.

But I believe you're more concerned about the developers perspective. Probably the most common way is to use the [libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq.html) library that comes with PostgreSQL. It is well documented and rather stable. Integration into your software project should be straightforward.

If you are looking for an Objective-C framework, you could try out [BaseTen](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/baseten-framework). Never used that one, though.

If you want more specific help, you have to ask more specific questions.